# How to save a image from stream as Jpeg

Tags: c#, image-processing

This code segment saves the image in the same format as in the uploaded image ,

```
thumbImg.Save(targetPath, image.RawFormat);
```

Instead of  image.RawFormat how to save it as  jpeg

Comment: what is the type of thumbImg? Are you in WPF, Winform, or Web?

Comment: web application on IIS server written in C#.net

Comment: what is the exact type of thumbImg?

Comment: uploaded image jpeg format

Comment: I understand, i am asking if thumbImage is System.Drawing.Image type?

Comment: yes you are correct

Answer (score 0):

For windows phone 8.1 I found the following to work well. Create your TempStorageFile at whatever path you would like and then pass in your image's stream like so:

```
var fileStream = await TempStorageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
await RandomAccessStream.CopyAsync(imageStream, fileStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [ImageFormat.Jpeg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.jpeg?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_Jpeg)

```
thumbImg.Save(targetPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```